# Lua script: embed C code to run automatically at the start of a while loop

Tags: c, loops, lua

So I want to make the while loop (in lua) run some custom c code without having to write it in the lua script.

I defined a function in c which updates an opengl window, and I want lua to run it every time a while loop starts.

If this is not possible, could I create a custom loop to do the same?

EDIT:

So, let's use this lua sample:

```
while mode == 0 do
    Window_Update()--will draw some images
    move_images(image_index, x, y)
end
```

I want to hide the Window_Update() so that from lua script you can only move the images, and not redraw them again on top.

Window_Update() is just a function defined in c to update a window and draw images, nothing special.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the expression in the condition of while-loop?

Comment: why does `Window_Update` have to be in the while-loop? if you dont want it to run repeatedly placing it right before the while-loop seems like the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

I discovered I must use threads to get the desired effect.

Thanks anyway.